# Is it possible to launch VSCode and have it access a folder of code on my development VM from my host machine?

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code

When I SSH into my development VM and want to open something in VSCode, I cannot do so from the command line. Obviously that makes sense because the `code` command runs on the remote server which has no idea about the host.

When running `code` from a VSCode integrated terminal using the SSH plugin will however open another VSCode window for that remote folder.

Is it possible to run a command (like `code ./foldername`) on my SSH connection and have that command do something on the host (e.g. open VSCode)? From a normal terminal window over SSH? Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Your code on your local machine should be for development and code on a remote server should be just that: Deployed code. In the world of modern programming, you should be able to develop locally and just shoot code to a server. What you are describing is effectively attempting to jump through hoops for what benefit?

Comment: My development environment is inside a virtual machine. I use vscode locally and connect to the vm using ssh. I'm essentially trying to achieve a hand-rolled wsl2

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I edited your question to clarify that. Wanting to do this with a local VM is a different thing from just a generic remote server access with the same goal. If not technically but at least conceptually; the value is clearer and valid if the VM is stated as the “remote” machine.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks

Comment: Still unclear: Where do you want VSCode to run, where is the project, where do you want to enter the command? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc The development environment is on their VM. They want to be able to launch VScode on their host machine and access the folder content on the VM.

Comment: And to the original poster, [this other question](https://superuser.com/a/1407902/167207) is for macOS but otherwise seems 100% the same desire being addressed. The solution was to use sshfs to mount the directory on the VM and then working within that mounted directory. It mentions using [FUSE](https://superuser.com/q/179436/167207) for file system compatibility but that might not be needed. The overall concept is the same: Mount the directory from the VM “remotely” on your host and away you go!

Answer (score 0):

A solution is described in the Microsoft article
[Remote Development using SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh).

This solution involves running a VScode server on the remote machine and a development
VScode instance on the client machine.

The exact process is described in the article (and may change in the future).
It requires installing on the server VScode the
[Remote Development extension pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack).
On the client VScode you start by selecting "Remote-SSH: Connect to Host..."
from the Command Palette (<kbd>F1</kbd>) and using the same `user@hostname` from
the SSH connection.

The article illustrates the process with the following diagram:

[image]